# How do I prove that the infinite union of this specific family of closed sets in $\mathbb R^2$ is neither open nor closed

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

We observe the vector space $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the Euclidean Norm, for each $k \in \mathbb{N_0}$ we define the  set $M_k$ as follows:
$$M_k=\Bigg\{x\in \mathbb{R^2}\bigg|\Bigg\|x- \begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{2^k} \\ 0  \end{pmatrix}\Bigg\| \leq \frac{1}{2^{k+1}} \Bigg\}.$$ Then we define the union of sets $M_k$ as follows: $$M=\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{N_0}}M_{k} $$
Now here is what I wish to ask and what I need help with. I have several assumptions, first is that $M_k$ constructs a closed ball for each $k\in\mathbb{N_0}$ although I think a proof by induction is possible I haven't been able to prove it. My second assumption is that the Union $M$ is neither closed or open but unlike the first assumption I have no idea how to even proceed, any help to this question would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you mean an infinite union (not a finite as the title says). Then such an infinite union is not necessarily close (as your example show), but may be closed for certain choices of sets you consider (e.g. $A=\bigcup_n A$ for one fixed closed set $A$).

On your particular example: The ball's centers provide a sequence in your union, which you may consider to show that not all (in $\mathbb{R}^2$) convergent sequences have their limit in your union. For the openness, the point $(\frac{3}{2},0)$ may be easiest to see, that there exists no ball of any radius around this point which still contained in your union. Can you now work it out yourself?